# Google cloud tutorial for tensorflow

Tags: cloud

I am trying to follow the tutorial on this page:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction

However, whenever I try, I get an error:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine local train \
>     --module-name trainer.task \
>     --package-path trainer/ \
>     --job-dir $MODEL_DIR \
>     -- \
>     --train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
>     --eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
>     --train-steps 1000 \
>     --eval-steps 100

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/63/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/63/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/simon/cloudml-samples-master/census/estimator/trainer/task.py", line 19, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: symbol __close_nocancel, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
```

above this error message when asking for help.

Does anyone have any advice?